# VS2010 code coverage not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I've got a solution in VS2010 where I can't get the code coverage working, I always end up with the error

```
"Cannot find any coverage data (.coverage or .coveragexml) files. Check test run details for possible errors.
```

I did set up everything as usual, so in the test settings I enabled the "Code Coverage" checkbox on the "Data and Diagnostics" page and chose the dll to be tested. I also added the "Re-signing key file" as we sign our assemblies. I don't know any other thing that prevents me from getting the coverage info, manually comparing the "Local.testsettings" for this solution with files from other working solutions didn't show any problems.

Any ideas what the reason might be and how to get it working?

Thanks in advance

G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright,

For some reason the Test Settings were changed from "Local (local.testsettings)" to "Trace and Test Impact (traceandtestimpact.testsettings)". Don't know why that happened, now it works again...